# Python Tesseract: int() argument must be a string, a bytes-like object or a number, not 'tuple`

Tags: python, machine-learning, tesseract, text-recognition, python-tesseract

I am a beginner in Machine Learning and I wanted to try text extraction code. Here is my code:

```
import pytesseract from PIL import Image 
pytesseract.pytesseract.tesseract_cmd = r"C:\Program Files (x86)\Tesseract OCR.exe" 
img = Image.open('image.png') 
img.load()
imgString = pytesseract.image_to_string(img)
```

However, this results in this error:

```
TypeError: int() argument must be a string, a bytes-like object or a number, not 'tuple`'
```

I am using Jupyter Notebook (python 3) to run this program. Is there anything I can do or is there an easier way to extract text from an image?

Comment: i think you dont need to call img.load()

Answer (score 1):

Image.load() method

Allocates storage for the image and loads the pixel data. In normal cases, you don’t need to call this method, since the Image class automatically loads an opened image when it is accessed for the first time.

```
img.load()
```

to

```
#img.load()
```

Comment: I removed this statement, and it still gives me the same error.

Comment: have you provided the valid path of tesseract binary ? @BobLee

Comment: yes, for some reason it works for some images and it doesn't work for others

Comment: can you check the shape of the images, for which it didn't worked

Comment: it seems to work with images with not a lot of noise. It doesn't work with images with rotated text, is there a workaround?

Answer (score 0):

Executable file name is wrong, Use below code you will get the answer

```
pytesseract.pytesseract.tesseract_cmd = "C:/Program Files (x86)/Tesseract-OCR/tesseract.exe"
```

Other lines of code is file. Thank you